# How do I pass the specific value that is clicked, in php?

Tags: php, html

I have these values in a table

```
<td>
<a href ="test.php>
<h4><?php echo $result_array[$i]['email_number']."<br>"; ?>
<h4>
</a>
</td>
```

and when I click on the value, I want 'email_number' in test.php. Any guidance would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a query to `test.php`:

```
<a href="test.php?email=<?php echo $result_array[$i]['email_number'] ?>">
```

In this way you add a value in `GET` to `test.php` call and you will have like:

```
test.php?email=google@gmail.com
```

In `test.php` you can call:

```
echo $_GET["email"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @AIS if my answer helped please mark as right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <td><a href ="test.php?email_number=<?php echo $result_array[$i]['email_number']; ?>><h4><?php echo $result_array[$i]['email_number']."<br>"; ?><h4></a></td>
```